# Can't trust them WITH IT/USING IT (a pager as a communicator)

Tags: sentence-meaning

In the movie Captain Marvel, she was sold out by Nick Fury, as Nick Fury had thought captain Marvel was an enemy.
What is the difference between these two sentences: (Nick Fury used an old pager to communicate)

> captain Marvel to Nick Fury: "You obviously can't trust them **with it"**

Vs.

> captain Marvel to Nick Fury: "You obviously can't trust them **using it"**

If I were to say that, I would use sentence 2, since it's more common to my ear.

Answer (score 1):

To say that **you can't trust somebody with something** is a general way of expressing doubt that the person involved is either mature, honest, capable, responsible or experienced enough to do something.

The **something** can vary from a small task such as walking the dog to overseeing a department of government or captaining an ocean liner.

This expression can also refer to somebody's inability to keep a secret. It just refers to the person's unreliability in some respect.

To say that **you can trust something using it** refers to some unspecified object. It might be a firearm, a vehicle, a machine or just a penknife.

The difference is that the first expression can refer to anything under the sun while the second refers  specifically to the use of a particular object.